# Animated Image File in Windows Live Movie Maker?

Tags: animation, gif, windows-7

I have created an animated gif file in Imageready CS2 which I was trying to import in Windows Live Movie Maker but failed. In the net I found a way around by converting the gif into mp4. I used an online conversion utility which did the job. But the quality of the mp4 file and subsequently the movie file was horrible. Mind you the gif quality was pretty good.

What to do? Any other way around?

Answer (score 1):

The quality of a gif is intrinsecally bad becouse the reduced colors pallete.

If the gif is not the exact same size of the video thoose defects will show, which eventually will happen becouse a video is resized all the time.

Try exporting your Imageready into separate png files (24 bits, not 8 bits.

Asamble them in a program like virtual dub, and export a video from there. (Virtual dub also can import animated gif files)

You need to control the output format of the video, which is out of the range of this forum.

Comment: I am actually trying to insert an animation 10% the size of the video deck. What you're suggesting is save that all image frames (32 nos) into PNG and make one single video?

Comment: Of course when you blow your gif from 10% to 100% the defects will show. Movie maker resamples the images to fit the video size, so you need to make again your animation or put a big background the size of your final video.

Comment: OK let me try both actually. First let me break them into small images and make a mp4 before trying to import it into my movie. Secondly let me try to make the size of the animated gif (only black color used) the size of main background with majority of the background color being set to transparent. Let's then convert it into mp4 and import in movie. Thanks. Will let you know the results.

Comment: I can't import all the png files in VirtualDub.